# My printers don't work anymore since last update

Tags: 16.04, printing

Both printers aren't working anymore since my last update yesterday.

A internal error reporting box fires up, when I try to add another printer under system settings. Here is some info:

- Executable Path: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cups-pk-helper-mechanism`
- Package: `cups-pk-helper 0.2.5-2ubuntu2`
- ProblemType: Crash

  ```
  cups-pk-helper-mechanism crashed with signal 5 in g_variant_new_va()
  ```

Found this: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-pk-helper/+bug/1565170

This is the error firefox-printer dialogue shows:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: My best guess based on the limited information you have provided is that something is awry with [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cups-pk-helper-mechanism](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/cups-pk-helper/filelist) or one of it's configuration files. Have you tried removing and reinstalling the package? What have you tried?

Comment: I'd need a routine for this. I only did run the weekly ubuntu update and it's not working anymore since this.

Comment: cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cups-pk-helper-mechanism ->
bash: cd: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cups-pk-helper-mechanism: Is not a directory

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-pk-helper/+bug/1565170

Comment: Good find. Subscribe to the bug so that you can be notified when it's squashed. Meanwhile you may want to https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get  Previous releases of `cups-pk-helper` can be found [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/cups-pk-helper/releases/)

Comment: doing *sudo apt-get purge cups* and then *sudo apt-get install cups --install-suggests* fixed the problem for me....

Answer (score 2):

Unless you truly need the fine grain priveleges that cups-pk-helper provides, you might try simply removing the package with `sudo apt-get remove cups-pk-helper` if that fails, you can [purge the package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application) where packagename is `cups-pk-helper`

You might also take a look at [this related post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794588/how-to-remove-imagemagick-without-breaking-its-dependencies)

Comment: I tried both (remove and purge), but I still receive the same error under firefox-printing (see screenshot above). I also got the same exclamation mark under printer settings on the specific printer.

Comment: Turned out, cups wasn't installed anymore and has been removed with my deinstallation of imagemagick without asking back.