# I have ImageMagick installed but I can't uninstall

Tags: uninstall, imagemagick

You can see with this pictures the ImageMagick software is installed.

[image: screenshot of GNOME Activities, in which an ImageMagick appears]

And:

[image: screenshot showing ImageMagick running]

But if i try unistall:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-all imagemagick
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove imagemagick which isn't installed
```

```
$ snap remove imagemagick
snap "imagemagick" is not installed
```

I tried other forms too and none are working.

Comment: How you uninstall software depends entirely upon how you originally installed it. How did you install Imagemagic? Ubuntu Software application? Snap? AppImage? Some other way? Dpkg is not magical: It can only uninstall deb packages -- it doesn't know anything about any of the other methods.

Comment: It you installed  a snap, a `snap remove` will remove it... ie. what user535733

Comment: I don't installed

Comment: Yes, the How to remove duplicate imagemagick icons answer my question.

Comment: @N0rbert Whats i need do now ? You put the comment in the answer box ?

Comment: Does `sudo apt remove imagemagick` work?

Comment: Removing imagemagick will break your system. The choice is yours. https://askubuntu.com/a/794602/243321